# Trouble playing audio files in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button which when clicked plays an audio file and then when it's clicked again plays the next file in my array. I get it to play but when I click it the second time it plays both the first file AND the second. When I press it the third time it plays the first, second and third. Seems like I need to reset something or other to clear the first two tracks of the page. Here is what I have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        audio = new Array('audio1.mp3','audio2.mp3','audio3.mp3');
        index = 0;

        function playSound() {
        if(index<3){
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML=document.getElementById("start").innerHTML +
        "<embed src=\""+audio[index]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
        index++;
        }
        else{ index = 0;
        document.getElementById("start").innerHTML=document.getElementById("start").innerHTML +
        "<embed src=\""+audio[index]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
        index++;
        }



    }

     </script>

                <button id="start" type = "button" onclick="playSound();">Start</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function playSound() {
    if(index>=3){
         index = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+audio[index]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
    index++;
}
```

And add a div (which u can make hidden as well with css), I thinks that's a better way than adding the html to the button.

```
<button id="start" type = "button" onclick="playSound();">Start</button>
<div id="sound" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: How do I accept the answer, sorry, I'm still learning! I tried your answer and it solved the problem of playing multiple files at the same time, however the button itself loses its text and halves in size. I appreciate your response, thank you!

Comment: Ah that's because you add your hidden embed elements to the button. I'll edit my answer to fix that. You can accept my answer by pressing the V thingy on the left side of my answer.

Comment: OK I have accepted now, thanks for the info. I created a div and added it to that instead. It didn't change the button but just nudged it down. I guess I just have to find a way to hide the div better. There must be a better way though. I'll keep trying! Thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't play at all if I add "display:none"

Comment: Excuse me, `style="visibility:hidden"` will do a better job then.

Answer (score 1):

You are continuously adding more and more `<embed>` elements, never removing any of them.

Instead of appending them to the button, append them to a container and then remove them before adding another one.

Comment: I tried this but got into a mess. As you may have guessed I'm still very much a beginner at javascript. How do I remove an embeded element? I found this : element = document.getElementById("element-id"); but didn't seem to work. I presumed you had to add an id to the embeded element but I think maybe that was wrong. I have much to learn I know haha. Thanks for your help.
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);